# Making a grid for a board game out of a 2D array

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I will try to be as specific as possible and also express myself in a manner that is acceptable. I hope will not offend anyone by phrasing my question in a bad way. I am fairly new to Python and I hope to get my mind elevated by experts.

So to the problem..:

I am currently taking baby steps towards creating a board game. I have come to the follow point (be prepared to see my code):

```
def createGrid(rows, cols):
grid = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
print(grid)

createGrid(3,4)
```

and this will output

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Which is exactly what I want. A 2D-array. This is supposed to be the grid of my board game.

The next step for me, is to make every one of the internal lists to a row. (I know that they already are that) but they are currently all smeared on a line. And I am wondering: how would one go by to arrange the internal lists so that it looks like a legitimate matrix?

So like a rectangle with the internal lists stacked onto each other.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You mean you want it printed in three separate lines? With or without the `[` and `,`s? (Which are added by Python's default to-string method for a list.)

Comment: Preferably without the brackets. A next step would be to only parse everything with "_" but thats a later step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to [pretty print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) it:

```
import pprint

pprint.pprint(grid)
```

Or you might choose to render it yourself:

```
for row in grid:
    print('>>', row, '<<')
```

Or:

```
for row in grid:
    for elt in row:
        print(f'({elt})', end=' ')
    print('.\n')
```

Or consider jumping into [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

Comment: I think I prefer leaving out the option of print statements in my function. So I will definitely look into numpy. Thanks for the tip sir.